# Accessing a local variable using prototype

Tags: javascript

I have a Class that has a private variable with a public setter/getter function:

```
function Circle(rad) {
    var r = rad;

    this.radius = function(rad) {
        if(!arguments.length) return r;
        r = rad;
        return this;
    }
}

var shape = new Circle(10);
console.log( shape.radius() ); // 10
shape.r = 50;
console.log( shape.radius() ); // 10
```

How can I replicate this using `Object.prototype`? Or, when would I want to use a closure instead of `Object.prototype`? This is the closest I could come up with, but as you can see, you can change the property directly.

```
function Circle(r) {
    this.r = r;
}

Circle.prototype.radius = function(r) {
    if(!arguments.length) return this.r;
    this.r = r;
    return this;
};

var shape = new Circle(10);
console.log( shape.radius() ); // 10
shape.r = 50;
console.log( shape.radius() ); // 50
```

Comment: Do you, or do you not want to be able to set it from the outside?

Comment: I want it to be accessible through the public getter/setter functions that I define. I don't want anyone outside of the class to have public access to the variable directly.

Comment: "How can I replicate this using the class's prototype object?" I don't really understand the question. Why would you want to replicate a certain behaviour with a language feature that might not be supposed to implement it?

Comment: @Wex This isn't Java. The only answer is "stop wanting to do this", and prefix "private" fields with an underscore or something. (Or use the closure as before, unless you have a reason not to.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use the prototype to store an object's properties, they are accessible from any code that has a reference to the object. It's impossible to do what you want.

What many JS devs do is just name private properties with a leading underscore so that others know not to mess with it, but it doesn't give you any real protection beyond a *suggestion*

**Reasons to use closure based approach**

- True private variables, be confident that no one will mess with your privates

**Reasons to use prototype**

- Less memory used (no closures for every instance)
- Easier to debug (properties are visible on the object itself)
- Allows monkey patching

Readers: Please edit the answer with reasons for whatever you think is the best solution.

Comment: Is there any downside to just sticking with my first version of code? Or is there an alternative that would perhaps be better?

Comment: The downside is that a new closure is created for each object, extra memory. I'm not paranoid about private properties, I use underscores to denote private. If anyone touches it outside of the class, I bash them over the head until they learn not to!

Comment: So it's better practice to use Object.prototype over creating closures?

Comment: I can't say one is better than the other, I prefer the prototype approach. I told you the benefits, you can make your decision. If you're paranoid about private variables and don't think developers will follow the pattern, then you should use closures. If you trust the people that are going to use the code, I would always use the prototype approach for its flexibility (and the ease of debugging, it's much easier to inspect properties on the object itself than those stored in a closure.

Comment: Another reason to use the prototype is to allow monkey-patching of your classes. That can be a good and a bad thing, so use it wisely. I often create my own patches for JS libs, that can only be done if it uses the prototype approach. You have to understand that if you do monkey patch something, you may be breaking things, but it's often better than waiting for a new release and being at the mercy of the lib developers. Monkey patching allows you to modify existing code without touching the source, so makes it easier to merge code when upgrading the library.

Comment: @Wex Downside of your first approach is that it's slower and uses more memory.  Every instance will get a branch new copy of that `radius` function with a different privileged scope.  That function takes time to generate, and memory to store each copy of it.  Putting the function on the prototype directly solves both these issues, because you declare the function once and all other instance simply get a reference to it.  That said if you don't instantiate tons of these objects, then it may not make a noticeable real world performance difference.

Comment: @AlexWayne Didn't I already say that? If you have more reasons for one or the other, please update the question itself.

Comment: @JuanMendes you did, I had some refresh fail... :)

Comment: @JuanMendes This answer does not answer the question and is wrong on top of that. -1

Comment: @PointedEars Don't be a troll and please enlighten us by telling us why it doesn't answer the question and why it's wrong. The OP obviously thought it answered the question. The answer to the question is it cannot be done. I think you misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

I find your first Circle very odd.  If you re-write it like this:

```
        function Circle(rad) {
            var r = rad;

            this.radius = function(rad) {
                if(rad){r = rad;}
                return r;
            }
        }
```

I think it now does what you mean. r is private and radius acts as a getter/setter function.
Setting r like this:

```
shape.r = 50;
```

doesn't make sense because your first Circle doesn't have a property r, it only has a locally scoped variable r.  It should raise some kind of error.

I can't see a way of using prototype in your second version of Circle because the function in the prototype chain wouldn't have access to a variable created in the Circle object. And anyway, in your second version, r is a property of Circle not a privately scoped variable in the function body.

Comment: What if you set the radius to 0? Your code change will ignore it. There's nothing wrong with the approach in the OP and your suggestion has nothing to do with the real issue.

Comment: Because of Javascript's dynamic nature, setting `shape.r = 50` would create a public property `r` with a value of `50`.

Comment: To explain what Wex mentioned, JS allows you to create properties on any objects. `shape.r = 50` just sets a property on the object (and that property will never be read)

Comment: Juan and Wex, there is something wrong with the approach in the first Circle in the OP.  The problem is readability.  You're right that the moment you write shape.r, a new property is created, but because of the way the code is written, it might look like Wex is trying to address the private variable r.  That's why it looked muddle-headed to me. It would not raise an error - that's my mistake.

Comment: Juan is also right that if I pass 0 to the radius function, r will be unchanged.  It was just a quick and dirty example to highlight what I saw as the main problem. We could easily add a better test like Wex's original `if(!arguments.length)` or something more robust.  Checking the parameter wasn't the main focus of the code snippet. I still can't see what Wex achieves in the radius function by returning `this`.  Shouldn't it be r?

Comment: @user341180 This is the pattern used by jQuery. The same function can be used as a setter or a getter. If you pass in a value, it's a setter and returns `this` so it can be chained. If you don't pass in an argument, it's a getter and returns the requested value.

Comment: Thanks Juan.  Beginning to see where your 11k reputation comes from! I still think readability is an issue. I follow Doug Crockford's advice about always using braces for if statements. Still, I wouldn't have grasped that setter/getter pattern without your explanation even if it was more readable. A bit too tricky for my taste.  Anyway, thanks for the help.